# Onclick Google sheet action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, onclick, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

I find this code in tutorial for google sheet, but it is not working for me. I can not understand why..

Code should recorder and save in log when user click on button and also save his name which he input.

Code.gs

```
    function doGet(e) {
  //Logger.log(e.parameter);
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page")
 }

 function userClicked(name){
   
   Logger.log(name+ " clicked the button");
  }
```

page.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Hello </h1>
<label> Name: </label> <input type = "text" id = "username">
<button id = "btn"> Click Here! </button>

<script> 
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

   function doStuff(){
     var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
     google.script.run.userClicked(uname);
     document.getElementById("username").value = "";
   }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Hello </h1>
<label> Name: </label> <input type="text" id="username">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me" onClick="doStuff();" />
<script>
   function doStuff(){
     var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
     google.script.run
     .withSuccessHandler(function() {document.getElementById("username").value = "";})
     .userClicked(uname);
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

gs:

```
 function doGet(e) {
  //Logger.log(e.parameter);
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah2");
 }

 function userClicked(name){
   Logger.log(name+ " clicked the button");
  }
```

I just added the withSuccessHandler to indicate that I was getting a complete path from client to server and back.

Comment: Thank you. 
But I still have nothing in my log... 
I have copied code and created ah2.html page

Comment: Did you deploy as a web app?

Comment: Yes. I have made new deployment now.  And it is working. Thank you.

Comment: hmm, but how to clear more cells  with function .withSuccessHandler(function() ?? For example I have first name and last name. I have tried many modifications of your code but none of it works ...

Comment: I reloaded it and redeployed it.  I ran it and it came back and deleted my entree and when I looked at the executions I could see the user clicked message in the logger output.  So there's something your not doing.  I don't know how to help you.